# rounded corner control

Tags: asp.net, imaging

I'm looking for a .net imaging control to use in a generic handler to process images. Right now I'm using OnlineImageOptimizer, which is a great component for resizing on the fly.

What I would love to do is take a photo, resize to the right dims, round off the corners, throw in a drop shadow and optimize into a small, high quality jpg.

Anybody have any experince with a control to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I like ImageGlue: http://www.websupergoo.com/imageglue-1.htm

Follow the docs and you'll find a way for using an alpha channel -- you would create a mask for the rounded corners and apply it to your image.

Drop shadows can be achieved with CSS: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/onionskin or with a control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/ImageShadow_UserControl.aspx

Comment: Matt,

It is true that you can get drop shadows with CSS, but not the nice, soft ones you can get with photoshop, which is what I'm looking for.

John